# ngx-typeahead not displaying collection from REST call

Tags: javascript, html, angular, async-await, ngx-bootstrap

After trying with angular-material, I've gone back to ngx-typeahead

What I'm trying to do is to have a typeahead that will make a REST call to a geolocation service once the user has typed something in the input box

I've tried to build a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dIoTyBVQEqkw7cSi0l4B?p=preview), but it just won't pick up the dependencies, so I gave up on that

The issue I have is that I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
```

Here is the html implementation of the typeahead:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <pre class="card card-block card-header">Model: {{locations | json}}</pre>
      <div class="container">
           <input name="searchBySiteName"
                  id="field_searchBySiteName"
                  [typeahead]="locations"
                  [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
                  (typeaheadOnSelect)="showAlert"
                  placeholder="Locations loaded with timeout"
                  class="form-control"
                  [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="7"
                  typeaheadOptionField="name"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

The json pipe shows the results in locations just fine after the user inserts a character in the input box

My TS code:

AsyncSelected and locations definition:

```
locations: any;
asyncSelected: string;
```

Constructor:

```
constructor(/*several properties*/) {
        this.locations = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
            observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
        }).mergeMap((token: string) => this.searchSites(token));
    }
```

Async methods:

```
waitForReturn(){
        return Observable.of(this.locations);
    }

    async searchSites(term: string){
        await this.searchAllSitesFromGeoNamesAPI(term);
    }

    searchAllSitesFromGeoNamesAPI(term: string){
        this.formService.querySitesByName(term).subscribe(
        (result) => {this.locations = result,
            console.log('here now '+ this.locations),
            this.waitForReturn()},
        (error) => this.locations = error
    );}
```

Service methods:

```
  private resourceQuerySitesByNameFirstHalf = 'http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=';
  private resourceQuerySitesByNameSecondHalf = '&maxRows=10&username=myUsername';

querySitesByName(term: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.resourceQuerySitesByNameFirstHalf+term+this.resourceQuerySitesByNameSecondHalf}`);
}
```

**EDIT:**  I've put my code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmrhv7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html), the demo picks up the dependencies, but fails with another error I don't understand either

**EDIT 2:** The app on stackblitz is generating two errors: one is because of mixed content (https environment doing call on http resource), that error is fine, the one that concerns me is the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`  This is the one that stops the data from being displayed on my dropdown

Comment: does your api return the proper names? because the error message kinda suggests its returning null or nothing or some http error.

Comment: If you want to share your code you can use https://stackblitz.com instead of plunker

Comment: @floor yes, the api returns everything in style, I check that in the <pre> tag with the json pipe

Comment: @pioro90 I will try and do that tomorrow, not in the office anymore, thank you!

Comment: @Steven is locations an array? because it would need to be an array.

Comment: Hi, yes, it becomes an array when the REST call resolves itself

Comment: @floor I've updated my question with a link to stackblitz, now it collects the dependencies just fine.  I get two errors, as described in question, the only one that concerns me is the second

Comment: @Steven its likely something to do with this.locations not being an array. try this.locations = []; just above where you are assigning it to an observer

Comment: @floor I have an assignment like that already:  `locations = [{id:1, name:'trialone'}];`  EDIT; I've added that line regardless and it still fails with the slice error

Comment: @Steven try moving this.locations .... in constructor to  ngOnInit()

Comment: I take it you mean the whole line where I assign an observable to it?  Done it and saved in stackblitz, same error pops up

Comment: @Steven i cant run the stackblitz im on a phone so I am kinda just guessing. Would you mind commenting the observable part out and just assign an array of objects (more than a couple) to see if it works with a regular array

Comment: Yep, as soon as I comment out the observable, it takes the objects from the first declaration of locations (`locations = [{id:1, name:'trialone'}];`)  BTW no need to apologise, I really appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Tried the following: `searchAllSitesFromGeoNamesAPI(term: string) {
     this.formService.querySitesByName(term).subscribe(
       (result => { this.locations = result;
        console.log("here now " + this.locations);
         return Observable.of(this.locations); }), 
        error => (this.locations = error)); }` Same error :(

Comment: So, doing this it prints an unknown error + the already known slice error I've also tried by assigning the array values, same result

Comment: @Steven im out of options haha i think the confusion is coming from using async await functions which return promises and a stream is not a promise. maybe you need to use something like Observable.fromPromise . And you are assigning this.locations to an observable that somewhere down the line reassigns this.locations so maybe don't assign this.locations initially and wait for the endpoint observable to assign this.locations but still have it initialized to an array.

Comment: Yeah, I will give that some time and hope for the best, thank you for all the ideas!

Comment: Yeah, just need it to populate from a REST call eventually, don't really mind at all which type of functions I use

Comment: @Steven can the endpoint call to that external service return all the locations if you dont specify a term?

Comment: No, the service holds 11 milion locations, I will eventually need the query to start with a timeout that gives user time to type at least 3 characters,so it narrows down the search even more